# How to change {app} variable in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

So far I use `{app}` to represent the path that was chosen by users (to install my application).

```
[Files]
Source: {app}\myexe.exe
```

Now I want to extend the installation and support silent install as well.

Since I have dozens of {app} calls, I'm wondering whether I can just change the value of `{app}` (in the beginning before installation starts) in case that silent install is launched? This way I should not change my code where `{app}` is already used.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`/DIR`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=DIR) parameter in the command line that runs your setup to specify the absolute path of the target directory, e.g.:

```
setup.exe /SILENT /DIR="C:\My Program"
```

Or, if you would like to expand a built-in constant in the path, you could use e.g.:

```
setup.exe /SILENT /DIR=expand:{pf}\My Program
```

The reference describes this parameter as:

> Overrides the default directory name displayed on the Select
>   Destination Location wizard page. A fully qualified pathname must be
>   specified. May include an "expand:" prefix which instructs Setup to
>   expand any constants in the name. For example: '/DIR=expand:{pf}\My
>   Program'.